# lodash Array _includes

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How do I pass an array in lodash?

```
users = [{
            name: 'aaa', age: 22
},{
            name: 'bbb', age: 33
},{
            name: 'ccc', age: 44
},];
this.selection = _.filter(users, function(p) {
       return _.includes(['aaa', 'bbb'], p.name);           
    });
```

the above code works fine I get all the details of user aaa and bbb

however if I do something like 
    this.testuser = ['aaa', 'bbb'];

```
this.selection = _.filter(users, function(p) {
           return _.includes(this.testuser, p.name);           
        });
```

it complains about this.testuser?

Thanks!

Comment: `this.selection = _.filter(users, (p) => {
           return _.includes(this.testuser, p.name);           
        });`

Comment: Thanks works great!

Answer (score 0):

Within the [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) the scope is different means `this` refers to something else(most of the case `window` object) so you can't access `this.testuser` inside the function since which is defined in a different scope.

To make it work use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)(which doesn't have its own bindings to the `this`) instead of [traditional function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) syntax.

```
this.selection = _.filter(users, p => _.includes(this.testuser, p.name));
```

---

You can do it using native Javascript functions and no need for lodash.

```
this.selection = users.filter(p => this.testuser.includes(p.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` inside the function will bind to the anonymous function which does not have `testuser` variable. So you can either use the `arrow function` as mentioned in the comment or can use `bind`

```
this.selection = _.filter(users,
    (function(p) {
        return _.includes(this.testuser, p.name);           
    }).bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

As **@Pranav C Balan** pointed out in their comment, the keyword `this` is binding to the function that you are passing to `_.includes()`. If you supply an arrow function, like so, it will bind to your class:

```
this.selection = _.filter(users, (p) => { return _.includes(this.testuser, p.name); });
```

Another alternative is to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), as mentioned by **@brk**

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is accessing `this` inside of a callback that is called in a different context. You can use arrow functions or bind to solve it.

However, instead of solving the `this` problem, you can solve the problem of selecting items from one array, by using values from another array, with lodash's `_.intersectionWith()`. Since you don't use `this.testuser` inside the callback function, you won't have the same problem.

```js
var users = [{"name":"aaa","age":22},{"name":"bbb","age":33},{"name":"ccc","age":44}];

var obj = {
  testuser: ['aaa', 'bbb'],
  selection(users) {
    return _.intersectionWith(users, this.testuser, function(a, b) {
      return a.name === b;
    });
  }
};

console.log(obj.selection(users));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```